# INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Not working! Inserting new rows instead?

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, on-duplicate-key

I have a dataframe, df, I want to update on duplicate keys but new rows are appearing instead? I'm using the code below. Why is this happening? The Mysql 'table' structure may be impacting  this as it has two primary keys? ID Column is a Primary Key, and IDT Column is a Primary Key, Unique & Auto Increment Assigned. Any ideas?

```
df = df[['ID', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']]
df = df.values.tolist()
query = """INSERT INTO table(ID, aa, bb, cc)
           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
               aa = VALUES(aa),
               bb = VALUES(bb),
               cc = VALUES(cc);"""
cursor.executemany(query, df)
```

Comment: A mysql table can have only 1 primary key - please publish your table definition and tell us which values you think should cause a duplicate key test to react.

Comment: *The Mysql 'table' structure may be impacting this as it has two primary keys?* Noway, as P.Salmon said. But it can have a lot of UNIQUE indices.

Comment: There could be a _composite primary key_, if that's what you meant?